# How to Schedule tasks in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

Following this [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) I set up a basic Spring Boot Scheduler. When I run the `SchedulingTasksApplication` below, it repeatedly prints the logs as expected.

### `ScheduledTasks` class

```
package com.climate.schedulingtasks;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledTasks.class);

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void reportCurrentTime() {
        log.info("The time is now {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

### `SchedulingTasksApplication` class

```java
package com.climate.schedulingtasks;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulingTasksApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SchedulingTasksApplication.class);
    }
}
```

I then added a `ProducerService` to produce 5 messages. I tried adding the notations to connect to the `SchedulingTasksApplication`, but when I run it, I never see the `ProducerService` called.

### `ProducerService` class

```java
package com.climate.eventplatform.client.jobs.heartbeat;

import com.climate.eventplatform.client.EventPlatformClientException;
import com.climate.schedulingtasks.ScheduledTasks;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class ProducerService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledTasks.class);

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public static void main(String[] args) throws EventPlatformClientException, InterruptedException, IOException {
        HeartBeatProducer.produceAll("Producer 1");
        log.info("Producer Running");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does your service have a main function? Your Spring boot app should just have one main function. `psvm` is your starting point for the application, 2 starting points makes no sense. Try making it a simple `public void` function, it'll work.

Comment: Looks like I also needed to add the annotation `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.climate.schedulingtasks", "com.climate.eventplatform.client.jobs.heartbeat"})` Do you think that's right? I also had to get rid of the parameter list.

Answer (score 1):

By default , spring-boot will scan and register beans that are under all sub-packages of the package of `@SpringBootApplication` class (see [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using.structuring-your-code.locating-the-main-class) for more details)

Now your `@SpringBootApplication` is in `com.climate.schedulingtasks` package but `ProducerService` is in the package `com.climate.eventplatform.client.jobs.heartbeat` which is not under `com.climate.schedulingtasks` , so it cannot be scanned.

You can specify all packages that to be scanned explicitly like what you mentioned in the comment . Or just move `ProducerService` to any packages under `com.climate.schedulingtasks`